# Why my Next Auth is getting authorize without credentials data?

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to implement login with `NextAuth` in my application, I already did all the steps that all videos or forums ask for, but I'm able to log to my application without providing any `email or any password`, looks like my `authorization` from `NextAuth` is being ignored.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'password', type: 'password' },
      },

      async authorize(credentials) {
        return (
          axios
            .post(`https://backend-test.tickr.com.br/auth/login/`, {
              data: JSON.stringify({
                email: credentials?.email,
                password: credentials?.password,
              }),
            })
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data)
              return response.data
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error.response)
              throw new Error(error.response.data.message)
            }) || null
        )
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/',
  },
}

const handler = NextAuth(nextAuthOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```